# haskell Non-exhaustive patterns in function code

Tags: string, function, haskell

i'm a beginner in haskell… 
i'm trying to write a function short:: String -> String that encodes a string with only contains the following characters:

```
moni :: Char -> String
moni 'm' = "01"
moni 'o' = "1"
moni 'n' = "001"
moni 'i' = "11"
short :: String -> String
short x = moni 'x'        -- here i try that short m = "01" but it doesn´t work…. why?)
in ghci: 
short m        -- error variable not in scope 
short "m"      -- error Non-exhaustive patterns in function code
```

In the end the function short should return only a string of bits … 
example "omi" should yield "10111"....

Comment: Shouldn't this be `short x = moni x`? RIght now you pass the `'x'` char to `moni`, and hence it will indeed not match with any of your patterns.

Comment: Well what *should* `moni 'x'` return? You haven't included a case for that in the definition of `moni`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think manu is imagining that `short`'s functionality is to wrap its argument in single quotes before calling `moni` with it. Convert a bareword into a character, so to speak, but of course Haskell doesn't have barewords.

Comment: @amalloy, ah, indeed, I did not notice the signature, then it is `[x]`.

Comment: i think short m give out "01"
because short m = moni 'm'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write `'x'`, you do *not* use the variable `x`, you used a *character literal*.

If you want to "unpack" a string, such that you retrieve the only character, then you can use:

```
short :: String -> String
short [x] = moni x
```

since a `String` is just a list of `Char`s. But the above will not work for a string with no characters, or two or more. If you want to map every character to its `moni` equivalent, and concatenate the result, you can use `concatMap`:

```
short :: String -> String
short = concatMap moni
```